# Scrolling textfield above keyboard flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

when I click on a reactiveRawAutocomplete the keyboard is displayed but it hides the reactiveRawautocomplete I have tried a lot of solutions but it does not work.
i tried to put ClampingScrollPhysics() for the SingleChildScrollView i also tried resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
I use reactive form package and reactiveRowautocomplete.

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RecommandeScaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        headerTitle: createAccountTitle,
        headerIcon: backArrow,
        showBottomNavigationBar: false,
        showLogoutBtn: false,
        showQrcodeBtn: false,
        body: BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => locator<AuthentificationCubit>(),
          child: BlocBuilder<AuthentificationCubit, AuthentificationState>(
            builder: (context, state) => BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => locator<UploadMediaCubit>(param1: null),
              child: BlocBuilder<UploadMediaCubit, UploadMediaState>(
                  builder: (context, uploadMediaState) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: CreateAccountFormBuilder(
                            initState: (context, formModel) {
                              context
                                  .read<AuthentificationCubit>()
                                  .createAccountForm = formModel;
                            },
                            builder: (context, formModel, child) => Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 20.0,
                                right: 20,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                key: ObjectKey(state),
                                children: [
                                  if (state.zipCode.isNotEmpty)
                                    ReactiveRawAutocomplete<String, String>(
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                        key: ObjectKey(state),
                                        validationMessages: {
                                          'required': (error) => zipCodeError,
                                        },
                                        formControl: formModel.zipCodeControl,
                                        /* items: state.zipCode
                                            .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                                  value: e,
                                                  child: Text(e),
                                                ))
                                            .toList(),
                                        onChanged: (zipCode) {},*/
                                        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue
                                        textEditingValue) {
                                          return state.zipCode
                                              .where((String option) {
                                            return option
                                                .toLowerCase()
                                                .contains(textEditingValue.text
                                                .toLowerCase());
                                          });
                                        },
                                        optionsViewBuilder:
                                            (BuildContext newContext,
                                            AutocompleteOnSelected<String>
                                            onSelected,
                                            Iterable<String> options) {
                                          return Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                            child: Material(
                                              elevation: 4.0,
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: 200.0,
                                                child: ListView.builder(
                                                  padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                  itemCount: options.length,
                                                  itemBuilder:
                                                      (BuildContext listContext,
                                                      int index) {
                                                    final option = options
                                                        .elementAt(index);
                                                    return GestureDetector(
                                                      onTap: () {
                                                        onSelected(option);
                                                      },
                                                      child: ListTile(
                                                        title: Text(option),
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                       ),

                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

can someone tell me what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)`  to `Padding` , try to put it in correct Padding widget.